# Navigate User from slack channel to app home tab

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am working on a slack app that can be installed in any channel. It is possible or is there any slack method that allows you to open the slack app home tab from the channel. I mean a method that can navigate the user from the  channel to the slack app home-tab

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Send a slack message to users with @appname. For example "Click here to open the `@ACME Dashboard`" (assuming "ACME Dashboard" is the name of your app). `@ACME Dashboard` will turn into a clickable link that jumps to the app home page. It'll also add the app for users that haven't already added the app.

At least, this worked for me in limited testing with myself and one other person, so I hope it works for you. I haven't tried to figure it out, but I'm sure there's a way to send the '@app name' as part of a message from the API.